# Need to update a record before deleting in a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2016

I have two tables a Master (tblField) and a Slave temporal audit table (tblFieldTemporal). I need to update a row in the tblFieldTemporal with some user details then delete it when the corresponding row in the tblField is deleted.

I've tried an After Trigger and a Instead Of trigger and both together with the update statement in the instead of trigger and the delete in the after delete trigger to achieve this. But I cannot get the update to commit before the row is deleted, so I never see the user details

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[tblField_Temporal_DeleteTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[tblField]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    -- delete from main table
    delete t
    from dbo.tblField t
    inner join deleted d on t.intFieldId = d.intFieldId;

    -- add user / dates etc before temporal delete
    update t
        set     t.[vcrUserID] = 'SFPFieldUse',
            t.dteAuditDate = getdate()
        FROM [dbo].[tblFieldTemporal] t
        inner join deleted d on t.intFieldId = d.intFieldId;


    --delete from temporal table
    DELETE t
        FROM [dbo].[tblFieldTemporal] t
        INNER JOIN deleted d
          ON t.intFieldId = d.intFieldID;

END
```

Both deletes fire correctly, but the temporal delete doesn't have the updated user and audit date values. I guess this is because it hasn't been committed, before it is deleted.

I want the deleted row to show in the Temporal history with the user and audit date values.

Comment: Are these actual temporal tables, or home-grown? Or is `tblFieldTemporal` the one that has temporal enabled, so there is a 3rd table here that has the history of the audit table? If you update a row that you then delete in the next statement, what was the purpose of the update, given that it's a single transaction? There is no period of time where that update is readable by other transactions except with loose isolation like read uncommitted and timing luck involving purple horseshoes.

Comment: *"But I cannot get the update to commit before the row is deleted"* you won't be able to. *Everything* within the trigger is run inside the **same** transaction. They will all be committed at the same time; when the DML statement completes, trigger and all. If you need to process things in a certain order, and have them commit **before** the `DELETE` a `TRIGGER` is the wrong choice. I would suggest using an SP to handle your deletes and handle the transactions in there.

Comment: ^ yes, please enforce DML through a stored procedure, then you don't have to look for hacky solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the tblFieldTemporal is a system versioned table. tblField is a very old table accessed by lots of different code in lots of different places, that I may or may not have access to. In doing the update on tblFieldTemporal I'm trying to ensure that the record in the actual temporal table (tblFieldTemporalHistory - the 3rd table) shows who deleted it and when. It looks like I may have to execute the Update through an SP before calling the tblField delete.

Comment: The temporal table should show when the record was delated (ValidTo), and you're hard-coding the user as `'SFPFieldUse'`, so I'm not sure what either gains you. Also if `tblField` (what an odd name) is only for backward compatibility, why not change it to a view against `tblFieldTemporal` instead of maintaining two tables? Sounds like a total mess.

Comment: This is a cut down example. 'SPFFieldUse' was dummy data in place of the actual user details for this question. Yes, the Valid To date is usable in this regard, but i actually need more data to go in on the update. So the premise remains.